# How to use omp parallel for and omp simd together?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, x86, openmp, simd

I want to test `#pragma omp parallel for` and `#pragma omp simd` for a simple matrix addition program. When I use each of them separately, I get no error and it seems fine. But, I want to test how much performance can be gained using both of them. If I use `#pragma omp parallel for` before the outer loop and `#pragma omp simd` before the inner loop I get no error as well. The error occures when I use both of them before the outer loop. I get an error at runtime not compile time. `ICC` and `GCC` return error but `Clang` doesn't. It might be because `Clang` regect the parallelization. In my experiments, Clang does not parallelize and run the program with only one thread.

The program is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <x86intrin.h>
#define N 512
#define M N

int __attribute__(( aligned(32))) a[N][M],
    __attribute__(( aligned(32))) b[N][M],
    __attribute__(( aligned(32))) c_result[N][M];

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    #pragma omp simd
    for( i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<M;j++){
            c_result[i][j]= a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error for:
ICC:

> IMP1.c(20): error: omp directive is not followed by a parallelizable
>   for loop      #pragma omp parallel for    ^
>
> compilation aborted for IMP1.c (code 2)

GCC:

> IMP1.c: In function ‘main’:
>
> IMP1.c:21:10: error: for statement
>   expected before ‘#pragma’   #pragma omp simd

Because in my other testes `pragma omp simd` for outer loop gets better performance I need to put that there (don't I?).

Platform: Intel Core i7 6700 HQ, Fedora 27

Tested compilers: ICC 18, GCC 7.2, Clang 5

Compiler command line:

`icc -O3 -qopenmp -xHOST -no-vec`

`gcc -O3 -fopenmp -march=native -fno-tree-vectorize -fno-tree-slp-vectorize`

`clang -O3 -fopenmp=libgomp -march=native -fno-vectorize -fno-slp-vectorize`

Comment: Have you tried also `#pragma omp parallel for simd`?

Comment: `#defien M N` Is that actually in your code or a typo when asking the question here?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, a typo when I simplified it here.

Comment: Although icc implements parallel for simd (gcc will ignore simd), it isn't the right method for this case, where the inner (but not the outer) loop can use simd effectively.  So you can place omp simd on the inner and omp parallel on the outer, but you will likely run into memory bandwidth saturation, so will not see ideal speedup.  Whether omp simd has an effect on the inner loop depends on compiler and chosen options.

Comment: @tim18, so GCC (even now in 2023), say ``GCC 11`` , ignores the ``#pragma omp simd`` directive? thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From OpenMP 4.5 Specification:

> **2.11.4 Parallel Loop SIMD Construct**
>
> The parallel loop SIMD construct is a shortcut for specifying a parallel
>   construct containing one loop SIMD construct and no other statement.
>
> The syntax of the parallel loop SIMD construct is as follows:
>
> `#pragma omp parallel for simd`
>   ...

You can also write:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp for simd
   for ...
}
```

Comment: This approach works, but I think vectorization is not good as it could be. `pragma omp simd` works very well in ICC but this approach does not vectorize most of the implementations.

Comment: I rechecked and Yeah,  this approach is not good for mixing TLP and DLP. Even ICC is confused! But, Thank you! You saved a lot of time for me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Martin I guess your algorithm is bounded by memory bandwidth, which generally hinders scalability of both vectorization and multithreading. There are 2 loads and 1 store per single arithmetic operation, i.e., quite high byte/op ratio. If you want to learn more about this problem, look for "memory wall" and "roofline model".

Comment: Thank you, I noted those phrases. You are right, I tested Matrix-Matrix Addition, Matrix Transposition, Matrix-Matrix Multiplication, Finite Impulse Response (FIR) filter, Sum of Absolute Differences (SAD), Sum of Squared Differences (SSD), and Matrix Convolution Algorithms which all are bounded by memory bandwidth (I guess).

Comment: How could one write `parallel` parameters (Like `private`, `first`, etc...) and `simd` parameters?

Comment: @Royi This is an off-topic question here, but if you use a split `parallel` and `simd` pragmas, what is the problem?

Comment: I don't think it is off topic. It just make the answer complete. Probably when it is splitted no problem. The question is what's the right syntax in the joint form.

Comment: @Royi Sorry, but I disagree. OP didn't ask for this in their question, therefore it is a good candidate for a separate question.

Comment: Are you targeting the OP or generating content others will use? I searched for parameters, this is the answer I get. I think it is always better to be broad and complete in order to prevent fragmentation in knowledge. Anyhow, thank you for that information.

Comment: @All right. Just see the [relevant section of the specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu67.html#x94-3240002.13.5): _clause can be any of the clauses accepted by the `parallel` or for `simd` directives, except the `nowait` clause, with identical meanings and restrictions_.